# Declare global variable using an "artificial" symbol

Tags: common-lisp

By "artificial", I mean one created from a string using `intern` or `make-symbol`.
I have a section of my code that declares up to 49 global variables:

```
(defparameter *CHAR-COUNT-1-1* (make-hash-table))
...
(defparameter *CHAR-COUNT-1-7* (make-hash-table))
...
(defparameter *CHAR-COUNT-7-7* (make-hash-table))
```

I thought, instead, I could create a function to do all that:

```
(loop for n from 1 to 7 do
  (loop for i from 1 to 7 do
    (defparameter (symbol-value (intern (concatenate 'string "*CHAR-COUNT-" (write-to-string n) "-" (write-to-string i) "*")))
                  (make-hash-table :test 'equalp))))
```

But get the error(sbcl):

```
unhandled SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                    {1002978EE3}>:
  Can't declare a non-symbol as SPECIAL: (SYMBOL-VALUE
                                          (INTERN
                                           (CONCATENATE 'STRING "*CHAR-COUNT-"
                                                        (WRITE-TO-STRING N) "-"
                                                        (WRITE-TO-STRING I)
                                                        "*")))
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Embedding dimension info into a variable name seems like it really should be a different data structure, like a two-dimensional array. But if you really want to do that, one easy way is via macrolet.

Comment: Drop SYMBOL-VALUE for a start; you don't want the value of the symbol… you'd also need to either macroexpand DEFPARAMETER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of "use a macro that returns a `PROGN` with `DEFPARAMETER` stanzas" or "use [`PROCLAIM`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm), it is a function, not a macro".

Answer (score 5):

Defparameter is a macro, not a function.  That means that it defines a special syntax.  The defparameter form needs to have a symbol as its second argument, but you're providing the list:

```
(symbol-value (intern (concatenate 'string "*CHAR-COUNT-" (write-to-string n) "-" (write-to-string i) "*")))
```

What you want is a *form* like

```
(progn 
  (defparameter *foo-1-1* (make-hash-table ...))
  ...
  (defparameter *foo-n-n* (make-hash-table ...)))
```

You seem familiar enough with loop and creating the symbols to create that list; just change

```
(loop … do (loop … do (defparameter …)))
```

to

```
`(progn 
  ,@(loop … nconcing
      (loop … collecting
        `(defparameter ,(intern …) …))))
```

and you can get the form you need.  Then it's just a matter of putting it all into a macro

```
(defmacro … (…) 
  `(progn 
     ,@(loop … nconcing
         (loop … collecting
          `(defparameter ,(intern …) …)))))
```

and calling the macro.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use a proper data structure instead of encoding dimensions in symbol names.  Do you really want to calculate and encode symbol names any time you want to access the correct table?

```
(defparameter *char-counts* (make-array '(7 7)))

(dotimes (i 49) ; or (reduce #'* (array-dimensions *char-counts*))
  (setf (row-major-aref *char-counts* i) (make-hash-table)))
```

Now you can access the array of tables just with the indices (`x` and `y` in this example):

```
(gethash (aref *char-counts* x y) :foo)
```